# Can we implement a coroutine type of functionality in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to see if there anyway a single thread in Java can switch between tasks where each task is an infinite loop ?

I have the following code and I am wondering if there is any possible way I could make the count for all three jobs below change while they run on single thread? perhaps using wait/notify?

I was able to change the count only for one job but not for all three jobs.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class Job implements Runnable {
    protected int count;
    public Job(){
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        while(true) {
           this.count = this.count + 1;
           System.out.print("");
        }
    }
}


public class ThreadTest {

    static int tasks = 3;
    static Job[] jobs = new Job[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
            jobs[i] = new Job();
            executor.execute(jobs[i]);
        }

        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
           for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
              System.out.print(jobs[i].c + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
           try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I just edited my question by describing my objective in the first line in case if I am not clear

Comment: `ThreadPool` and `Runnable`/`Callable` task are the building blocks upon which higher levels of abstraction can be introduced. There is no built-in facility to relinquish control the way you want it.  One approach is to switch to Kotlin and use its coroutines (which behind the scenes rely on thread pools and tasks in case of async execution).

Comment: @yegodm can I introduce sleep and interrupted exception in that infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your current code doesn't work can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-):

> If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they
>   will wait in the queue until a thread is available

Your first Job is running forever and so the other Jobs are never taken off the queue.

One way to solve this would be by having each Job add itself to the back of the queue once it's completed one iteration. This allows other items in the queue to be given time to execute:

```
class Job implements Runnable {
    protected int count;
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    public Job(ExecutorService executor){
        this.count = 0;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        this.count = this.count + 1;
        System.out.print("");

        executor.execute(this);
    }
}
```

And you'd need to change

```
new Job();
```

to

```
new Job(executor);
```

Answer (score 0):

No: when a thread is allocated to a task, it executes the `run()` method. When the run method returns or when there is an exception, the next task will be allocated to the thread.

Comment: so I can introduce an interrupted exception in the code above?

Comment: @user1870400 sure: it would just end the task. Is this what you want?

Comment: The number of tasks is 3 in my code above and I dont want to end those tasks because each task is doing an increment in an infinite loop. And I want those 3 tasks to keep incrementing their count but on a single java thread so introducing interrupted exception such that another task can run is completely fine for me..